# Excel: Copy to another sheet and past under the existing value

Tags: excel, loops, automation, copy, paste

First of all I am learning VBA new, thats why the code is very simple I think.

I made a macro with this logic:

- Step 1 :go on Sheet "table1" and copy cell "C1" & "E2"
- Step 2: Then go "table2" and Past cells in "A1" & "B1"
- Step 3: Delet in "table1" the Columns 1-10

**What I strugle now are these steps:**

- Step 4: Past the next copy cell from "table1" under the other values in "table2"
- Step 5: Run the whole "table1" till there is no value automaticaly.

Sub Mve()

```
Sheets("table1").Select
Range("C1").Select
Selection.copy
Sheets("table2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("table1").Select
Range("E2").Select
Selection.copy
Sheets("table2").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("table1").Select
Rows("1:10").Select
Selection.Cut
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

End Sub

Can anybody help me? Thank you:)

Comment: I would like to confirm if you are going to delete columns 1 to 10 in table 1? Since the code you have written is deleting rows instead.

Comment: Also, you can learn the `Do-while-loop` structure in VBA, where you can set the exit condition so the program will terminate if cell C1 and/or cell M2 is empty.